# Qt translator in VS 2010 - translation TS file names are put in the .pro file in Qt Creator, how is it done in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, language-translation

I have code in C++ which needs to work with the Qt translation tools.  In Qt Creator I would add

TARGET = translation
TRANSLATIONS = tran_ar.ts tran_en.ts tran_la.ts

into the .pro file.  The development is being done in VS 2010 (the Gui is working fine so Qt is integrated).  So where do I put this information in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2):

Try the menu entry of the Qt plugin for VS:

Qt > Add new translation file

Select project and language, VS should then add a blank xxx.ts file to your project under "Localization Files" or some such. The context menu entry for this file contains links to "lupdate" and "lrelease", so I *think* you don't even need to bother with pro and pri files you wouldn't really use in VS anyway (I checked that the .qm files produced by lrelease appear to contain all translated entries of the .ts files).